# NGINX: Force nginx to use all workers for load balance

Tags: nginx, lua

I am working with nginx and I need to test if all workers are sharing data correctly but at the moment only one worker is handling all requests.

My `worker_process` is set to 4, but still one worker is serving all request.

I can force it to include other workers by changing the amount of `worker_connections` to a really low value and spam nginx with a curl commands in a while loop. Maybe `max_conns` could work but i am using free version of nginx.

Is there more practical way to force nginx to use different workers?

My current setup is this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  5;
    multi_accept off;
    use        epoll;
}

server {
     listen       8081;
     server_name *.localhost;

     # max_conns = 3;

     set $upstreamserver "127.0.0.7:8080

    location =/worker {
        content_by_lua '
            ngx.say(ngx.worker.id())
            ngx.say(ngx.var.pid)
            ngx.say(ngx.worker.count())
        ';
    }

    location /basic_status {
        stub_status;
    }

    location / {        
            proxy_buffering             off;
            proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_pass                  http://upstreamserver;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you hit a limitation of epoll, not nginx or Lua. [This article](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-sad-state-of-linux-socket-balancing/) explains in detail what is going on.

If you really want to distribute the load more envenly across workers, the above article suggests to use the `reuseport` option on the `listen` directive ([docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)).

```
server {
     listen       8081 reuseport;
     ...
}
```

This is not the greatest option in all cases though as the latency might increase in some extreme cases.

Comment: Nice, thanks - didnt know about that option. I am using just for testing in development so it just what i need

Comment: I've tested that option a bit more.

The load is evenly distributed across workers, it slows down response time a bit (I am spamming the server with requests)

The workers are sharing a thread-safe table. And that option affects data sharing between workers, I think. When i trigger an update of data 2/4 workers pick up on the change. If I trigger 3 or 4 times  then everything is back to sync.

Without that option and extreme spamming one update is enough. 
Still it is good for testing, thanks

Just wanted to share if somebody has similar issue